# Como incluir un echo de php en una variable?

Tags: php, echo

pueda que esto parezca de lo más sencillo pero ya van 2 seamas intentando y no me da.
Estoy haciendo una web, y deseo crear una variable $title que contenga el texto y me muestre el año.
con php voy así

```
$title = "My awesome website | ¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? [Actualizado <?php echo date(' Y ');?>]";
```

Pero no me muestra el año sino el textoplano de lo que he escrito en la variable.
Uso esto por que todo lo voy a poner en un archivo llamado meta.php que se replicará por todas las páginas y con las variables se renellarán los campos.

este es mi meta.php

```
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords ?>" />
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description ?>" />
    <!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
    <meta property="og:locale" content="<?php echo $lang ?>" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title ?> "/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image ?>">
```

Esto para ahorrar tiempo y no tener que repetir el mismo código en cada página que se haga.

Si alguien sabe por favor me puede orientar.

Comment: Tienes que separar el PHP del string...

Comment: que no deberia ser concatenado ??? algo como `$title = "Tu Texto ".date('Y');`

Comment: Asi mismo @FranciscoNúñez :3

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dije antes, debes separar el código del string, y concatenarlo.

```
$title = "My awesome website | 
¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? 
[Actualizado " . date('Y') . "]";

echo $title;
//Salida=> 
My awesome website | ¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? [Actualizado 2021]
```

Comment: Esperaré a una aclaración sobre el meta.php no entiendo su utilidad

Comment: meta.php es el lugar donde se va a imprimir ... lo que concatenaste...

Answer (score 0):

`date()` es una función, y en PHP no puedes incluir funciones en cadenas, como sí puedes hacerlo con variables.

Esto no funciona, como has comprobado:

```
$title = "My awesome website | ¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? [Actualizado <?php echo date(' Y ');?>]";
```

Esto por ejemplo sí funciona. OJO, no hace falta el `echo` ahí, mejor construye la variable y luego impŕímela, o haz `echo` toda la variable.

```
$year=date('Y');
echo "<title>My awesome website | ¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? [Actualizado $year]</title>";
```

**Salida:**

```
<title>My awesome website | ¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? [Actualizado 2021]</title>
```

Aquí sí funciona porque usamos la variable `$year` dentro de la cadena, **no la función `date()`**.

Otra forma de hacerlo, como se ha indicado antes, sería concatenando:

```
echo "<title>My awesome website | ¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? [Actualizado ".date('Y')."]</title>";
```

O bien usando [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php) (impresión directa):

```
printf( "<title>My awesome website | ¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? [Actualizado %s]</title>",date('Y') );
```

O bien usando [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php) (impresión indirecta, si interesa guardarlo en una variable):

```
$title=sprintf( "<title>My awesome website | ¿Como incluir un echo de php en una variable? [Actualizado %s]</title>",date('Y') );
#Usar $title
```